# Run the same analysis on multiple files in the same folder in R

Tags: r, matrix

Here I am analyzing a transition matrix for one file in a folder. But I need to do the same for 78 other files in the same folder so, that I can get the average flow diagram from all the individuals.

```
library(RcmdrMisc)
BHFF_14h31 <-read.table("BHFF_14h31.txt", header=TRUE,row.names=1, sep="\t",na.string="", dec=",")
BHFF_14h31_m <- as.matrix(BHFF_14h31)

BHFF_14h31 <- colPercents(BHFF_14h31_m, 2)
transc <- colSums(BHFF_14h31)
transr <- rowSums (BHFF_14h31)
diversity(transc, index = "shannon")

plotmat(BHFF_14h31)
```

**Data:**

```
dput(BHFF_14h31)
structure(list(False.feeding = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Head.flagging = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), Inverse.wing.spreading = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Preening = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), Scratching = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Splashing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tail.wagging = c(1L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Wing.spreading = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("False feeding", 
"Head flagging", "Inverse wing spreading", "Preening", "Scratching", 
"Splashing", "Tail wagging", "Wing spreading"))
```

I know we can use loop, but I don't know how to do it.
For example, the data  looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUpcT.jpg)

Comment: Could you post an example data, e.g. `dput(BHFF_14h31)`?

Comment: I have added the picture. Sorry, I don't know how to add the matrix file here.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) why this is not entirely helpful. Please try to add your data example using as described above the `dput()` function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added the example data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you somewhere:

```
library(purrr)
list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

  
list_names <- purrr::set_names(stringr::str_extract(list_of_files, "[^_ ]+(?=\\.txt)"))


purrr::map2_dfr(list_of_files, list_names, function(x,y){
  
  dat <- read.table(x, header=TRUE,row.names=1, sep="\t",
                    na.string="", dec=",") |> 
    as.matrix()
  
  dat_percents <- colPercents(dat, 2)
  transc <- colSums(dat_percents)
  transr <- rowSums (dat_percents)
  diversity_number <- diversity(transc, index = "shannon")
  return(data.frame(diversity = diversity_number, file_name = y))
})
```

Comment: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': more columns than column names

Comment: I got this error.